# How to create an event entry on a web server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote

How can I create an event on a remote Windows 2008 server that is outside of my own network?

I'm aware of the `eventcreate` command in Windows, but it does not work with a computer that is not on the same network.

Is it possible?

This is what I currently have, but it does not work with a web address:

```
eventcreate /S exampleserver.com /U username /P password /T INFORMATION /SO "data-runner" /ID 666 /L APPLICATION /D "The data is ready to be fetched."
```

I'm trying to send a message to (poke) a web server about a job that was executed and that the web server need to perform some work locally. Alternatively, what method is available that do not require a software to be installed on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a simple website on the web server that writes to the event log.

A website to do this (in classic ASP with vbs) could look like this:

```
<%

strEventMessage = "The data is ready to be fetched..."

SET objShell = CREATEOBJECT("WScript.Shell")
objShell.LogEvent 4, strMessage

%>
```

More information on this method: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301309

Be sure to require authentication, you wouldn't want to just let anyone spam the eventlog anonymously